# How to overload = operator to get control of behavior depending on lvalue type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I got a object, which should be seamless act like a integer even it is wrapped by a smart pointer.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    operator int() const { return 42; }
};

int operator = (int &val, std::shared_ptr<MyClass> mc) { return val = *mc; } // does not compile

void main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> mc=std::make_shared<MyClass>();

    int test = *mc; // does compile, but I do not want to write the asterisk
    int test = mc; // does obviously not compile, but I want to have it like that
}
```

I want to get rid of the dereferencing asterisk. Is there a way to overload = for int types as lvalue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to achieve what you want. You can only overload the assignment operator for assigning to classes, and only inside the class at that. There is no way for you to change the semantics of assigning a `std::shared_ptr` into an `int`, as neither of them is under your control.

And let me add that it would be a bad idea to do so even if it was possible. Code should do what it looks like it will do. If I see code assigning a pointer into an `int`, I definitely *do not* expect the pointer to be dereferenced for the assignment. Always try to code to the smallest amount of surprises.

A different way to phrase it is that a very good code quality (and thus maintainability) metric is the number of "WTF?"s per minute you get during review. Try to avoid code which worsens this metric.

Comment: To my defense, the code sample does not reflect my actual code :-) I overloaded an + operator as some cast operator act wired for humans (not the compiler) in some situations and I was wondering if the topic above is possible.

Comment: +1 for "smallest amount of surprises" ;) Very important for flexible languages like C++ and Haskell (where, compared to C++, you can do *even more* strange stuff with operator overloading... The limits C++ sets for operator overloading are for a good reason.)